# franka_hw/FrankaModelInterface and franka_hw/FrankaStateInterface transmission has more than one joint issue

Tags: gazebo, urdf, ros-noetic, xacro

I'm launching two panda robots in gazebo to use them with a custom controller. I edited the original dual_panda_example.urdf.xacro in order to use it in simulation as my controller needs both `franka_hw/FrankaModelInterface and franka_hw/FrankaStateInterface`. I just took the original franka_robot.xacro file from the original repository and call the macros in the same way as in this file.

I dont get where is the error as launching a unique panda works perfect but in this case where I have two, so I guess it should be to add these lines to the urdf:

```
<!-- transmission tags for the robot -->
    <xacro:transmission-franka-state arm_id="$(arg arm_id_1)" />
      <xacro:transmission-franka-model arm_id="$(arg arm_id_1)"
         root="$(arg arm_id_1)_joint1"
         tip="$(arg arm_id_1)_joint8"
       />
```

This is my urdf:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="dual_panda" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <!-- add arms names prefixes -->
    <xacro:arg name="arm_id_1" default="right_arm" />
    <xacro:arg name="arm_id_2" default="left_arm" />

    <!-- load arm/hand models and utils (which adds the robot inertia tags to be Gazebo-simulation ready) -->
    <xacro:include filename="$(find franka_description)/robots/common/utils.xacro" />
    <xacro:include filename="$(find franka_description)/robots/common/franka_arm.xacro" />
    <xacro:include filename="$(find franka_description)/robots/common/franka_hand.xacro" />

    <link name="world"/>

    <!-- box shaped table as base for the 2 Pandas -->
    <link name="base">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0.5" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <box size="1 2 1" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="White">
                <color rgba="1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0" />
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0.5" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <box size="1 2 1" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
            <mass value="10.0"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.001" iyy="0.0" iyz="0.0" izz="0.001"/>
        </inertial>
        
    </link>

    <joint name="base_to_world" type="fixed">
        <parent link="world"/>
        <child link="base"/>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <!-- right arm with gripper -->
    <xacro:franka_arm arm_id="$(arg arm_id_1)" connected_to="base" xyz="0 -0.5 1" gazebo="true" safety_distance="0.03" joint_limits="${xacro.load_yaml('$(find franka_description)/robots/panda/joint_limits.yaml')}"/>
    <xacro:franka_hand arm_id="$(arg arm_id_1)" rpy="0 0 ${-pi/4}" connected_to="$(arg arm_id_1)_link8" gazebo="true" safety_distance="0.03" />

    <!-- left arm with gripper -->
    <xacro:franka_arm arm_id="$(arg arm_id_2)" connected_to="base" xyz="0 0.5 1" gazebo="true" safety_distance="0.03" joint_limits="${xacro.load_yaml('$(find franka_description)/robots/panda/joint_limits.yaml')}"/>
    <xacro:franka_hand arm_id="$(arg arm_id_2)" rpy="0 0 ${-pi/4}" connected_to="$(arg arm_id_2)_link8" gazebo="true" safety_distance="0.03" />

   
    <!-- right arm joints control interface -->
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_1)_joint1" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_1)_joint2" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_1)_joint3" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_1)_joint4" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_1)_joint5" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_1)_joint6" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_1)_joint7" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />

    <!-- left arm joints control interface -->
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_2)_joint1" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_2)_joint2" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_2)_joint3" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_2)_joint4" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_2)_joint5" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_2)_joint6" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_2)_joint7" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />

    <!-- transmission tags for the robot -->
    <xacro:transmission-franka-state arm_id="$(arg arm_id_1)" />
      <xacro:transmission-franka-model arm_id="$(arg arm_id_1)"
         root="$(arg arm_id_1)_joint1"
         tip="$(arg arm_id_1)_joint8"
       />

    <!-- right hand joints control interface -->
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_1)_finger_joint1" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_1)_finger_joint2" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />

    <!-- left hand joints control interface -->
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_2)_finger_joint1" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
    <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="$(arg arm_id_2)_finger_joint2" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />

    <!-- load ros_control plugin -->
    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so"/>
        <robotSimType>franka_gazebo/FrankaHWSim</robotSimType>
    </gazebo>

</robot>
```

I dont understand what this warning is trying to say, as of course I have more than one joints in the transmission.